# console c# - tik tak toe - saving the field?

Tags: c#

I am just in my early days of learning C# and I got the task to build a "Tik Tak Toe" - game via console application; but I have a huge problem seeing mistakes in my code: when I enter a line and a column, the program will just print the pawn and color from the first player. And somehow my second problem is, that when it comes to the next player, the console won't save the current game stats and will draw a new field.

What did I code wrong?

```
namespace Tik_Tak_Toe_
{
    class Program
    {
        static int[,] field = new int[3, 3];
        static Player[] p;
        static int i;
        static bool gamerunning = true;
        static Random rnd = new Random();
        static int currentplayer = 0;
        static int column;
        static int line;
        static int playercolumn = 7;
        static int playerline = 7;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            INITIALIZE();
            Console.Clear();
            DrawField();
            currentplayer = rnd.Next(1, 2);

            while (gamerunning==true)
            {
                UPDATE();
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void INITIALIZE()
        {
            playerconfiguration();
            DrawField();
        }

        static void playerconfiguration()
        {
            p = new Player[2];
            for (i = 0; i <= 1; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Player " + (i + 1) + ", enter your name!");
                p[i].name = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine(p[i].name + ", choose a color: ");
                ColorConfiguration();
                Console.WriteLine("... and your symbol example: X or O: ");
                p[i].pawn = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
                Console.WriteLine();
            }            
        }

        static void ColorConfiguration()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Type one of the following colors: blue, pink, yellow, white, red oder darkblue");
            bool whatcolorinput = true;

            while (whatcolorinput == true)
            {
                string whatcolor = Console.ReadLine();

                switch (whatcolor)
                {
                    case "blue":
                        p[i].color = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                        whatcolorinput = false;
                        break;

                    case "pink":
                        p[i].color = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
                        whatcolorinput = false;
                        break;

                    case "yellow":
                        p[i].color = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                        whatcolorinput = false;
                        break;

                    case "white":
                        p[i].color = ConsoleColor.White;
                        whatcolorinput = false;
                        break;

                    case "red":
                        p[i].color = ConsoleColor.Red;
                        whatcolorinput = false;
                        break;

                    case "darkblue":
                        p[i].color = ConsoleColor.DarkCyan;
                        whatcolorinput = false;
                        break;

                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Type one of the following colors: blue, pink, yellow, white, red oder darkblue");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        static void UPDATE()
        {
            DrawField();
            Console.WriteLine(p[currentplayer].name + ", it's your turn!");
            PlayerInput();
            UpdateField();
            currentplayer = (currentplayer + 1) % 2;
        }

        static void DrawField()
        {
            for ( column=0; column<field.GetLength(1); column++)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkMagenta;
                Console.Write((column+1) + "|");
                Console.ResetColor();
                for ( line=0; line<field.GetLength(0); line++)
                {
                    if (field[column,line]==0 && (column != playercolumn || line != playerline))
                    {
                        Console.Write("   ");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.ForegroundColor = p[field[playercolumn, playerline]].color;
                        Console.Write(" " + p[field[playercolumn, playerline]].pawn + " ");
                        Console.ResetColor();
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkMagenta;
            Console.WriteLine("  ________");
            Console.WriteLine("   1  2  3");
            Console.ResetColor();
        }

        static void PlayerInput()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("First, choose a column: ");
            bool columninput = true;

            while (columninput == true)
            {
                try
                {
                    playercolumn = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                    if (column < 1 || column > 3)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Choose a column.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        columninput = false;
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Choose a column.");
                }
            }

            playercolumn -= 1;
            Console.WriteLine("... and now a line");
            bool lineinput = true;

            while (lineinput == true)
            {
                try
                {
                    playerline = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                    if (line < 1 || line > 3)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Choose a line.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lineinput = false;
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Choose a line.");
                }
            }
            playerline -= 1;
        }

        static void UpdateField()
        {
        }

        static void FINISH()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Format your code, please.

Comment: Your code is not complete. The Player class is missing.

Comment: It's very general question. Best option would be to debug that yourself and to ask a question when you have a more specific problem. This msdn article on debugging should be a good start: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986851.aspx

Comment: As it currently stands, this question will be closed as: "*Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself*".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You've got a lot of problems in your code. First of all, you was never storing the player input in the `field` array, so obviously when you were redrawing the table, only the last input was drawn. You were also exchanging some variables as `line` and `playerline`. After solving this problems and some minor ones and adding a Player class (i hope it is more or less like this as you don't provided it) , the code that correctly draws the board is more or less this:

```
class Program
{
    static int[,] field = new int[3, 3];
    static Player[] p;
    static int i;
    static bool gamerunning = true;
    static Random rnd = new Random();
    static int currentplayer = 0;
    static int playercolumn = 7;
    static int playerline = 7;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        INITIALIZE();
        Console.Clear();
        DrawField();
        currentplayer = rnd.Next(1, 2);
        while (gamerunning == true)
        {
            UPDATE();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public class Player
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public char pawn { get; set; }
        public ConsoleColor color { get; set;}
    }

    static void INITIALIZE()
    {
        playerconfiguration();
        DrawField();
    }

    static void playerconfiguration()
    {
        p = new Player[2];
        for (i = 0; i <= 1; i++)
        {
            p[i] = new Player();
            Console.WriteLine("Spieler " + (i + 1) + ", gib deinen Namen ein!");
            p[i].name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(p[i].name + ", wähle deine Farbe: ");
            ColorConfiguration();
            Console.WriteLine("... und nun dein Symbol z.B. X oder O: ");
            p[i].pawn = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    static void ColorConfiguration()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Gib eine der folgenden Farben ein: blau, pink, gelb, weiss, rot oder dunkelblau");
        bool whatcolorinput = true;
        while (whatcolorinput == true)
        {
            string whatcolor = Console.ReadLine();
            switch (whatcolor)
            {
                case "blau":
                    p[i].color = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                    whatcolorinput = false;
                    break;
                case "pink":
                    p[i].color = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
                    whatcolorinput = false;
                    break;
                case "gelb":
                    p[i].color = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                    whatcolorinput = false;
                    break;
                case "weiss":
                    p[i].color = ConsoleColor.White;
                    whatcolorinput = false;
                    break;
                case "rot":
                    p[i].color = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    whatcolorinput = false;
                    break;
                case "dunkelblau":
                    p[i].color = ConsoleColor.DarkCyan;
                    whatcolorinput = false;
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Gib eine der folgenden Farben ein: blau, pink, gelb, weiss, rot oder dunkelblau");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    static void UPDATE()
    {
        DrawField();
        Console.WriteLine(p[currentplayer].name + ", du bist dran!");
        PlayerInput();
        UpdateField();
        currentplayer = (currentplayer + 1) % 2;
    }

    static void DrawField()
    {
        for (int line = 0; line < field.GetLength(1); line++)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkMagenta;
            Console.Write((line + 1) + "|");
            Console.ResetColor();
            for (int column = 0; column < field.GetLength(0); column++)
            {
                if (field[line, column] == 0)
                {
                    Console.Write("   ");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = p[field[line, column]-1].color;
                    Console.Write(" " + p[field[line, column] -1].pawn + " ");
                    Console.ResetColor();
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkMagenta;
        Console.WriteLine("  ________");
        Console.WriteLine("   1  2  3");
        Console.ResetColor();
    }

    static void PlayerInput()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Wähle zuerst eine Spalte: ");

        bool lineinput = true;
        while (lineinput == true)
        {
            try
            {
                playerline = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                if (playerline < 1 || playerline > 3)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Wähle eine Spalte.");
                }
                else
                {
                    lineinput = false;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Wähle eine Spalte.");
            }
        }

        bool columninput = true;
        while (columninput == true)
        {
            try
            {
                playercolumn = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                if (playercolumn < 1 || playercolumn > 3)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Wähle eine Zeile.");
                }
                else
                {
                    columninput = false;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Wähle eine Zeile.");
            }
        }
        playercolumn -= 1;
        Console.WriteLine("... und nun eine Spalte");


        //field[line-1, column] = new int();

        playerline -= 1;
        field[playerline, playercolumn] = currentplayer+1;
    }

    static void UpdateField()
    {

    }

    static void FINISH()
    {

    }
}
```

Study this code and compare it with yours to see what were your mistakes. Of course, you must still check if a position is alreay taken,when one player has won and when there are no moves left and the result of the game is a draw.

Comment: Thank you that answer really helped!

Answer (score 0):

You just have just global variables to store playercolumn and playerline.

Each time you execute PlayerInputyou will replace the values this variables had.

You will need a 3x3 matrix to store the player choices, then print this matrix as a board. Id a column and row was already chosen, you need to refuse the user input.

Looks like you want to store user moves in field global variable, but you're not assigning that anywhere.

I modified the code, in update, repeat the PlayerInput until a its valid for update:

```
do
{
    PlayerInput();
} while (!UpdateField());
```

In DrawField check onli for values in field variable, not the player input

```
static void DrawField()
{
    for (column = 0; column < field.GetLength(1); column++)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkMagenta;
        Console.Write((column + 1) + "|");
        Console.ResetColor();
        for (line = 0; line < field.GetLength(0); line++)
        {
            if (field[column, line] == 0)
            {
                Console.Write("   ");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = p[field[column, line] - 1].color;
                Console.Write(" " + p[field[column, line] - 1].pawn + " ");
                Console.ResetColor();
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkMagenta;
    Console.WriteLine("  ________");
    Console.WriteLine("   1  2  3");
    Console.ResetColor();
}
```

And implemented the UpdateField:

```
static bool UpdateField()
{
    if (field[playercolumn, playerline] != 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Column already chosen");
        return false;
    }
    field[playercolumn, playerline] = currentplayer + 1;
    return true;
 }
```

It still need to check when the game finish.